# Particle Systems adding margins and placing on top

Tags: particles

I am trying to place cubes on top of a plane using particle systems.
However, I have two 'constraints'.
I do not want my cubes to be going too near the edge of the plane. Therefore I kind of want to add a margin to my particles. (I don't want to use weight paint because I want to be able to automate this with the blender python framework.
Also, my cubes are currently going through the plane, whereas I want my cubes to be placed ON TOP of the plane.
What particle systems settings should I be looking at? I can't find anything helpful online except outdated responses.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will be changing the origin position of the cube. The particle system works by attaching the origin point of the selected object to the surface of another. By changing the origin point, we can also change the position of every particle on the object.

1. Select the object to be used as a particle (the cube in your case).
2. Go into edit mode, and press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all vertices.
3. Move the cube geometry.
4. Go out of edit mode. As you can see, the geometry of the cube should have moved, but the origin point remains the same, effectively changing the origin point of the cube.

[image]

As for the part where you need to add a margin, a simple fix that I thought of (and should be easy to make using python) is to duplicate the plane and scale it up. There are no settings in the particle system that allows you to create a margin to my knowledge that doesn't involve using some sort of painting.